# Combining two arrays into a new string array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Sorry for the confusing title but I'm not really sure how to explain in the title alone. I want to create a new array from two other arrays with words between the two of them. In other words I want to basically create this:

var author_title = ["authors[i] wrote books[i]"];

so one value of the array would be "Tolstoy wrote War and Peace." Obviously the code above doesn't work or else I wouldn't be here. So how can I combine these two arrays like so? Here is the code I have so far minus some of the html stuff.

```
var books = ["War and Peace","Huckleberry Finn","The Return of the Native","A 
Christmas Carol","Exodus"];

var authors = [];

for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
{

var name = prompt("What is the last name of the author who wrote " +books[i]+ 
"?");
authors.push(name);
}

document.write("***************************");

for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
{

document.write("<br>");
document.write("Book: "+books[i]+ " Author: "+authors[i]);


}
document.write("<br>");
document.write("***************************");

for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
{

var author_title = ["authors[i] wrote books[i]"];

}
```

Comment: `authors[i] + " wrote " + books[i]`

Comment: There is a perfect example in your posted code `document.write("Book: "+books[i]+ " Author: "+authors[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
{

var author_title = ["authors[i] wrote books[i]"];

}
```

with

```
var author_title = [];
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++)
{

author_title.push(authors[i] + " wrote " + books[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this a bit more elegantly using `map`

```js
const books = ["War and Peace","Huckleberry Finn"];
const authors = ["Leo Tolstoy", "Mark Twain"];

const author_title = books.map((book, i) => `${authors[i]} wrote ${book}`);
console.log(author_title)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const authorTitle = books.map((book, i) => `${authors[i]} wrote ${book}`);
```